# Is it possible to create custom Tensorflow GRU/LSTM cell?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to modify the `tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell` and add another gate to it for second input such that in addition to `z` – update gate and `r` – reset gate there would be third `g` - custom gate for the second input to the network similarly to [Kiddon et al. 2016](https://aclweb.org/anthology/D16-1032) and [Wen et al. 2015](http://www.emnlp2015.org/proceedings/EMNLP/pdf/EMNLP199.pdf).

[image]

I managed to do this for **Torch7** GRU cell and it successfully worked for the specific sequence modeling problem. I suspect this is not straightforward  to implement in Tensorflow but maybe I am wrong. Can somebody please provide more details on custom cells in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. As illustrated by [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) article, LSTM and GRU cells are just arrangements of non-linearities and arithmetic operations.

[This repository](https://github.com/gitabcworld/skiprnn_pytorch) contains custom LSTM, GRU and other RNN cell implementations for pyTorch.

[This repository](https://github.com/kaustubhhiware/LSTM-GRU-from-scratch) contains custom LSTM and GRU implementations for TensorFlow.